# Using CSS, is there any way to determine if an HTML element has a property set?

Tags: html, css, browser, properties, css-selectors

Using only CSS, is there any way to determine if a selected HTML element has a specific CSS property set?

As an example, if we have CSS of:

`.example { color: red }`

Is there any way in CSS to select `div[color has been set via CSS]`? (that's obviously *pseudo-code*, not real CSS)

This is trivial to accomplish when the HTML includes the style inline, but I am only asking about when the style is *not* defined inline within the HTML.

Comment: No for the obvious reason that you'd be able to do `[color:white] { color:black } [color:black] { color:white }`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, currently that can only target attributes on a tag, not styles that have been applied to it.

If you maybe describe what you are trying to do, there maybe an alternate way to achieve what you are trying to do.